# renderEvent fails after call to removeEvents - FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am fairly certain that this is a bug. Once I call remove "removeEvents", no subsequent adds ("renderEvent") work, and the ones that do act like they have no "stickiness".

If I do the following:

1. Initialize calendar.
2. Add event A using `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent, true);`
3. Remove this event using `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', 12345);`
4. Add event B using `$("##calendar").fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent2, true);`

Neither event A or B appears! Both events have different IDs, and what should happen is event A is deleted, but event should B appear. If I take this single "removeEvent" out, then both events A and B appear (even though the remove is only targeting the ID of event A).

Even if I rerender the events after step 4 using `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );`, still event B doesn't show.

What's more interesting is that this doesn't seem like simply a "rendering" issue since if I pull all events using `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', ...);`, it doesn't show event A or B in the array of returned events, where as removing the "removeEvent" will allow both events A and B to appear in the array.

The solution would SEEM to be do the remove AFTER all of the adds:

1. Add event A
2. Add event B
3. Remove event A

Which DOES keep event B, but in my app, I have drag-drop functionality, and the user can "add" new events at any time! So I am finding that as I call "removeEvent" then dragging a new event into the calendar makes the "stickiness" of the event go away, so change a month will not retain that added event.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     theme: true,
     header: {
         left: "prev,next today",
         center: 'title',
         right: "today prev,next"
     }, 
     height: 400,
     selectable: true,
     selectHelper: true,
     unselectAuto: false, 
     select: calendarSelect,
     droppable: true,
     drop: calendarDrop,
     events:getCalendarData,
     eventClick:calendarEventClicked
 });

 var newEvent = {
     id: 12345,
     period: "Full-day", 
     title: "Full-day",
     start: new Date(2010, 11, 02),
     type: "Regular", 
     billable: true,
     className: "",
     changedThisSession: true
 };

 $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent, true);

 $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', 12345);

 var newEvent2 = {
     id: 4433,
     period: "Full-day", 
     title: "Full-day",
     start: new Date(2010, 11, 03),
     type: "Regular", 
     billable: true,
     className: "",
     changedThisSession: true
 };
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent2, true);
```

Even though this code deletes event with ID 12345, the OTHER event (id 4433) is also not shown. Removing the line ..."removeEvents"... causes both events to show.

Again, I can add new events, drag them, etc, and it works great. As soon as "removeEvents" is called once, then things start acting weird.

Help would be appreciated!

-Brian

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded from 1.4.9 to 1.4.10, cleared my cache and tried again, and it now looks like everything is working properly.

Hopefully that was it.

-Brian